# Python variable assignment with : when building SQL query

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I've inherited some code and was curious as why it is being used and how it works. The code is as follows:

```
strsql: str = sql.SWAP_SQL.format(*sql_clauses)
```

No issue with the right hand side of the assignment, it's simply passing paramaters  to a sql string. I'm curious as to the `strSQL: str =` portion. What exactly is this doing as `sql.SWAP_SQL.format(*sql_clauses)` and `strsql` appear to have the exact same sql string?

Comment: is this python 3?

Comment: Yes running on PyCharm, Python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 (i think .5 but maybe earlier) introduced type hints for methods and variables. The hints do not [enforce](https://pypi.org/project/enforce/) the types (you can but not by default), they are there mostly for readability (basically just hinting the proper format).

[Pep-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#acceptable-type-hints) has some more details on method/class type hints, [Pep-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) has syntax guidelines for variable type hints (your example), and you can also check [typing library documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 0):

That is a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). It's hinting that the type of `strsql` is a `str`.